# Отсутствует файл error log

Tags: php, хостинг

На хостинге(cpanel) в диспетчере почему-то отсутствует файл error log, можно как-то настроить его отображение? добавление в начале проблемного скрипта строки error_reporting(E_ALL); не решает проблему.

Comment: Обычно в настройках есть логирование, и иногда его надо включать в ручную отдельно, что за хостер?

Comment: @Walfter a2hosting

Comment: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/cpanel/cpanel-logging-features/error-log первый результат гугла

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
ini_set("log_errors", true);
ini_set("error_log", "/полный путь до папки с доступом на запись /php-error.log");
```